# heroku error: Unable to connect to heroku API

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to access heroku from my command line, and I keep getting this same error: "Unable to connect to heroku API. Please check your internet connectivity and try again."

My internet connectivity is fine.

This question has been asked on StackOverflow before, but I don't quite understand the answer that seemed to be effective, as I'm a complete newbie. Apparently, it might have to do with an environment variable?

The other answer suggested a missing heroku remote branch, but mine is set up.

What, exactly, should I do to regain my connection with heroku?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Get the same message "Unable to connect to heroku API. Please check your internet connectivity and try again." when using heroku toolbelt on Mac.

In my case I installed the heroku toolbelt using homebrew. Installing the heroku toolbelt from https://toolbelt.heroku.com/ can solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems to have been a problem with my antivirus program . . . I reinstalled that, and heroku is accessible again.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re behind a firewall that requires use of a proxy to connect with external HTTP/HTTPS services, you can set the HTTP_PROXY or HTTPS_PROXY environment variables in your local developer environment, before running the heroku command.
For example, on a Unix system you could do something like this:

```
$ export HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.server.com:portnumber
or
$ export HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.server.com:portnumber
$ heroku login
```

On a Windows machine, either set it in the System Properties/Environment Variables, or do it from the terminal:

```
> set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.server.com:portnumber
or
> set HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.server.com:portnumber
> heroku login
```

I Got the same error on Mac OS X 10.13, and it's work for me, since I am behind the proxy,It's gathered from the Heroku Dev center page
 https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli